# XP domain login; connecting to printer in workgroup

Tags: windows-xp, printer, domain

I have a laptop with an XP domain login and would like to use a printer in a workgroup.
 How can I connect to the printer?

Comment: you should consult your IT department. i would certainly go berserk if users of our domain(s) go out and ask for advice in public forums (no matter ho well reputed) regarding our machines.

Comment: Is it a USB printer or networked (has an IP address)?

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that if you don't have admin control over your laptop you are usually stuck when it comes to adding printers. If this printer will only be used by you, companies with loose tech policies will allow the tech to install it for you. If not, then you may have to talk to someone higher up the corporate ladder to get approval.

Axxmasterr is mostly right when it comes to network printers. You can never be assured the same IP address for a device when you use DHCP. Unless you can get someone to reserve the IP address for the network card in the printer, that number may change at some point. In most cases, when working with DHCP, it's best to use the host name of the printer when possible. Usually, this is something you can control by going to the web management console for the printer. http://"printer's current ip address"

I would recommend that when you talk to people, you use the right language. Telling an IT tech that you want to go off the domain is a good way to get a long lecture. Saying you have a printer that you want to install locally usually goes down better. If you can get a hold of the technology policy for your company, you can usually figure out how big of a deal a new local printer would be.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a local printer connected via a USB or a Parallel cable, then  all you really need to do is hook it up and load the drivers.

If it is a network printer, configure the printer to use an IP address.  Sometimes the printer can pick up an address via DHCP.  Use DHCP if you have no control over the IP addressing scheme at your work.

Once you have an IP address for the printer, plug it in and then go configure it on the PC side.  Set up a local printer, then create a local "standard TCP/ip" port.  Make sure the port uses the same IP that the printer is configured with. Then load the printer driver via the add printer applet.

Print a page to make sure it works and then you are all done.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a batch file with something like:

```
runas /user:workgroup\username "net use lpt1: \\computername\printershare"
```

Then set up the printer on lpt1.